# Typescript type assignation

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm curently learning Typescript and I'm having an issue ...

**Type assignation for a function**

Here are 2 simple sample of code, which are compiling in a different way and I don't get the reason.

**1 Sample**

```
testP(): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("string");
    });
}
```

This code returning in error during compilation as I'm not returning a number, that's fine.

**2 Sample**

```
testP(): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("string");
    });
}
```

This code is compiling without any bug and I don't know why ...

WHat is my mistake ?
Thank you in advance !

Edit:

Here is what I'm actually trying to do

```
export interface Animal {
name: string,
weight: number,
age: number
}

getDogs(): Promise<Dog[]> {

return this.http.get('/dogs')
.toPromise()
.then(response => response.json())
.catch(this.handleError);
}
```

But like that, even if my "response" is not an array of "dogs", it doesn't trigger any error;

What am I missing ?

Comment: You don't mean [*assignation*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/assignation?s=t). You might mean *assignment*.

Comment: Never used Typescript, but I guess there's no way for the interpreter to know that your promise won't resolve as a number, so it assumes it'll be fine

Comment: @floribon: The question is about the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using? I don't see any errors in typescript playground.

Comment: I use version 2.0.2.
And I edited my question.

Comment: @Larxenne, I tried to answer with a second edit...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Apparently the word "assignation" does have a secondary meeting of "assigning something to something".

Comment: What's the difference between your two samples? My eyes aren't that good.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler cannot infer the return type of the promise from a call to `resolve`.

This code:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

... is a shorthand for:

```
return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
```

And then the type `any` is a way to disable type checking. Your second code compiles but it is wrong.

If you don't want to repeat yourself, you can do this:

```
let testP = function () {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("string");
    });
}
```

Here, the return type of the function is inferred to `Promise<string>`.

---

EDIT #1 (To answer to your answer): `Promise<any>` is compatible with `Promise<number>`, and `"string"` is also compatible with `any`. But `Promise<string>` is not compatible with `Promise<number>`. In fact, `any` allows you to do wrong code. When you use it, it's up to you to know what you are doing.

---

EDIT #2:

About this code:

```
export interface Dog {
  name: string,
  weight: number,
  age: number
}

function getDogs(): Promise<Dog[]> {
  return this.http.get('/dogs')
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The TypeScript compiler checks types *statically*. It can't check the type of a string value returned by the server, because, at run time, on the browser, there is just compiled code without types metadata at all.

TypeScript is like JSDoc. It helps to describe parts of your program. It can't help to check data that your program receives dynamically.

Comment: Yea you're completly right, it's a compiler so there is no way it can check the types of datas provided by a server ...

So here is my last question (I hope !).
In the Angular2 tutorial, they're using the type checking on a promise:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html (in the function: getHeroes).

Is this just like a code comment then ?

Thanks a lot for the time you used to answered me !

Comment: They use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions): `response.json().data as Hero[]`. It is a way to say to the compiler: "Trust me and consider that the object `response.json().data` is of type `Hero[]`". Yes, it is "like a JSDoc" here, too.

Comment: Now I get it !
Sorry, Typescript is really new to me and I'm still not really confident with it.

However, your explanations were really clear so thank you a lot once again.